# DataTables: Server-Side Processing - Button Function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I had to change over to Server-Side Processing due to very slow loading times on a large inventory table.

Due to AJAX limitations, I had to place the following line in the database table itself to ensure the button is created:

```
<td class='td-actions'>
  <input type="button" class="button_add btn btn-small btn-info" 
      name="add" id="<?php echo $row['inv_id']; ?>" value="+">
</td>
```

I also had to remove the  tags to accommodate the AJAX, which looks like this:

```
$columns = array(
  array( 'db' => 'inv_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
  array( 'db' => 'inv_item_code', 'dt' => 1 ),
  array( 'db' => 'inv_category', 'dt' => 2 ),
  array( 'db' => 'inv_desc', 'dt' => 3 ),
  array( 'db' => 'inv_price', 'dt' => 4 ),
  array( 'db' => 'z', 'dt' => 5 )
```

Where value [5] or "z" is the button which is read from the data table.

But nothing happens, as if the function is not initialized by the press of the button anymore.

[image: screenshot of datatable]

Following is the JavaScript for the button:

```
<script>
$('.button_add').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insert/add_item_test.php",
      data: {id: data},
      success: function(){

$('#table_refresh').load('insert/table_load_test.php').fadeIn("slow");
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("OOPS - Something went wrong, try again");
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No no no no you don't need to add html to your table. Just add a [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to your DataTables config.

Comment: Then create one with `targets: '.td-actions'` and return the desired markup on the render function

Comment: the buttons that you are creating, they are not in the DOM when the page loads for the first time. You bind a function to the '.button_add' elements when they don't exist yet. Try to add the js for the button AFTER refreshing the datatable

Comment: I am so lost right now, javascript loads just before html closing tag. The button is loaded with the ajax table builder row by row, as the button script is embedded in the database itself. I created the columnDefs line with targets, but nothing happens.